# Prove that $\mathbb{Q}(\sqrt{2})$ to be the smallest field that contains $\mathbb{Q}$ and $\sqrt{2}$.

Tags: abstract-algebra

In abstract algebra we define $\mathbb{Q}(\sqrt{2})$ to be the smallest field that contains $\mathbb{Q}$ and $\sqrt{2}$. In the most of textbox they usually write that this is.
$$\mathbb{Q}(\sqrt{2}) = \{a+b\sqrt{2}\mid a,b\in \mathbb{Q}\}$$
But can I prove that this is the smallest field that contains $\mathbb{Q}$ and $\sqrt{2}$.?

Comment: 1 : Prove that any field containing $\mathbb Q$ and $\sqrt 2$ must contain the set on the RHS (follows from closure under additivity and multiplication). 2: Prove that the set on the RHS is a field (hint : difference of squares / rationalization for proving existence of inverse element , the rest is easy).

Comment: Well if $K$ is a field that contains $\mathbb Q$ and $\sqrt 2 $ then clearly all elements of the form $a+b \sqrt 2$ where $a$ and $b$ are rational is contained in $K$, thus $\mathbb Q(\sqrt 2)$ is a subfield of $K$.